# IntelliJ JUnit Export Test Results adds the generated file to the project

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

The "Export Test Results" action has a few options. Why does it include the file in the project files? On subsequent exports, there is a popup:

> File 'Test Results - .xml' already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?

If you click Yes, the export will fail:

> "Test results export failed:  already exists in the VFS"

Is there a way I can disable this? This is with a Junit4 test, using IntelliJ 14. (TestNG shows the same behavior)

Comment: Android studio has the same problem. Would love to know the solution!

Comment: I haven't found a way to disable this, but should someone stumble upon this: I found deleting the test result instead of trying to overwrite it works for me